# Android: how to execute this for loop fast as now it is?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, pixel

I going to set the Pixel to my Bitmap to some specific point.

For that i am using the For Loop. But as because it is scanning whole image, it takes time. 
So what is the alternate of it that can help me to execute it faster.

That for loop is as below:

```
public void drawLoop(){
    int ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE = 100;

    for(int x = 0; x < mask.getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < mask.getHeight(); y++){

            g = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
            r = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
            b = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x000000FF);

            if(Math.abs(sR-r) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sG-g) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sB-b) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE)
                colored.setPixel(x, y, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000));
        }
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(colored);
    coloreBitmap.add(colored.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true));
    position = coloreBitmap.size()-1;
    System.out.println("Position in drawFunction is: "+position);
}
```

Please help me for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion to reduce the for loop by half. You should try with your images and see if it works.

Idea: By the assumption that the next pixel is same as current pixel, we only analyse the current pixel and apply the result to both current and next pixel.

Drawback: you have 50% chance to have 1 pixel distorted.

Example: Turn color 1 into 3

Original: 1 1 1 1 1 **2** 2 2 2 2 2 **1** 1 1

After for loop: 3 3 3 3 3 **3** 2 2 2 2 2 **2** 3 3 (Only 7 loops are executed. But color 2 shifted by 1 pixel.)

Using original logic, there will be 14 loops executed.

```
for(int x = 0; x < mask.getWidth(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < mask.getHeight() - 1; y+=2) { // Change point 1

        g = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        r = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        b = (mask.getPixel(x,y) & 0x000000FF);

        if(Math.abs(sR-r) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sG-g) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sB-b) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE)
            colored.setPixel(x, y, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000));
            colored.setPixel(x, y+1, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000)); // Change point 2
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer But with using this, result is not proper and even there is not any increment in speed.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem.
My program check every pixel on the bitmap, then checks if the green color (RGB) is higher then red and blue, an bitmap with the size of 3264 x 2448 (Samsung galaxy s2 camera size).
it takes 3 seconds to scan and check the whole bitmap, pretty fast if you ask me.

This is my code:

```
try {
                decoder_image = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance("yourfilepath",false);              

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

example filepath: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg

```
try {

                    final int width = decoder_image.getWidth();
                    final int height = decoder_image.getHeight();
                    // Divide the bitmap into 1100x1100 sized chunks and process it.
                    // This makes sure that the app will not be "overloaded"
                    int wSteps = (int) Math.ceil(width / 1100.0);
                    int hSteps = (int) Math.ceil(height / 1100.0);
                    Rect rect = new Rect();
                    for (int h = 0; h < hSteps; h++) {
                        for (int w = 0; w < wSteps; w++) {
                            int w2 = Math.min(width, (w + 1) * 1100);
                            int h2 = Math.min(height, (h + 1) * 1100);
                            rect.set(w * 1100, h * 1100, w2, h2);
                            mask = decoder_image.decodeRegion(rect,
                                    null);

                            try {
                                int bWidth = mask.getWidth();
                                int bHeight = mask.getHeight();
                                int[] pixels = new int[bWidth * bHeight];
                                mask.getPixels(pixels, 0, bWidth, 0, 0,
                                        bWidth, bHeight);
                                for (int y = 0; y < bHeight; y++) {
                                    for (int x = 0; x < bWidth; x++) {

                                        int index = y * bWidth + x;
                                        int r = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff; //bitwise shifting
                                        int g = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                                        int b = pixels[index] & 0xff;

                                       if(Math.abs(sR-r) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sG-g) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sB-b) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE)
                                       colored.setPixel(x, y, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000));
                                        }
                                }
                            } finally {
                                mask.recycle();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(colored);
                    coloreBitmap.add(colored.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true));
                    position = coloreBitmap.size()-1;
                    System.out.println("Position in drawFunction is: "+position);
                } finally {
                    decoder_image.recycle();
                }
```

I also cut them into chunks, because samsung galaxy s2 does not have enough memory to scan the whole bitmap at once.

Hope this helped.

**Edit:**

I just notice (my fault) it was about setting a pixel, instead of only read them. I going to try now to make it fit your code, changed already some to your code, I am working on it at the moment.

**Edit 2:**
Made an adjustment to the code, I hope this works.
Don't forgot to change `"yourfilepath"` at the top of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try on it and Will you please convert this code based on my images  ?

Answer (score 1):

iDroid,

You've got a very tough situation here. Whenever you do pixel by pixel operations, things get a little cumbersome. So, a bunch of minor optimizations are key, and I'm certain that many people will have a lot to add here. I'm not certain how much impact they will have in your overall process, but I know that these general behaviors saveme optimizing a LOT of code.

```
public void drawLoop(){
    int ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE = 100;

//EDIT: Moving this to outside the loop is FAR better
// Saves you an object call and the number doesn't change in the loop anyway.
    int maskHeight = mask.getHeight();
//EDIT: Reverse the loops. Comparisons vs. 0 are faster than any other number.
//  and saves you a ton of method calls.
    for(int x = mask.getWidth(); --x >= 0 ; ){
        for(int y = maskHeight; --y >= 0 ; ){
        //EDIT: Saves you 2 method calls for the same result.
            int atPixel = mask.getPixel(x,y);
            g = (atPixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
            r = (atPixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
            b = (atPixel & 0x000000FF);

            if(Math.abs(sR-r) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sG-g) <     ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(sB-b) < ANTILAISING_TOLERANCE)
                colored.setPixel(x, y, (colored.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000));
        }
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(colored);
    coloreBitmap.add(colored.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true));
    position = coloreBitmap.size()-1;
    System.out.println("Position in drawFunction is: "+position);
}
```

Aside from that, anything else will create "lossy" behavior but will have far higher yields.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. but still there is no any change in speed. Is there any other idea to increase its speed?

Comment: Absolutely! Look at Bigflow's answer! It's well applied. He simply splits the image into multiple parts. This can improve things considerably if you are working with a particularly large image. And combining it with the above should help.